# Control the printout of confidence intervals related to a linear model function

Tags: r, function, simulation, lm, confidence-interval

I am doing bootstrapping for a linear model but how do I edit the printout names of the intercept and the x variable?

Here are the simulated data

```
set.seed(42) 
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n)
e <- rnorm(n)
y <- as.numeric(50 + 25*x + e)
dd <- data.frame(id=1:n, x=x, y=y)
```

Here is the model:

```
mo <- lm(y ~ x, data=dd)
```

Find fit and residuals:

```
fit <- fitted(mo)
resi <- residuals(mo)
```

Function to retrieve confidence intervals based on the residual bootstrapping:

```
FUN <- function() {
  X <- model.matrix(mo)
  ressampy <- fit + sample(resi, length(resi), replace = TRUE)
  bootmod <- lm(ressampy ~ X-1)
  confint(bootmod, level = 0.95)
}
```

Output of 1 run (notice that the printouts are `X(Intercept)` and `Xx` but instead I just want them to be `(Intercept)` and `x`)

```
FUN()
                2.5 %   97.5 %
X(Intercept) 49.74439 50.07817
Xx           24.92904 25.25103
```

This may be a easy fix but I just couldn't get it to work.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `rownames()` to change the row names of the matrix containing the confidence intervals, as in:

```
FUN <- function() {
  X <- model.matrix(mo)
  ressampy <- fit + sample(resi, length(resi), replace = TRUE)
  bootmod <- lm(ressampy ~ X-1)
  ci <- confint(bootmod, level = 0.95)
  rownames(ci) <- c("(Intercept)", "x")
  return(ci)
}
```

Comment: Wow, simple as that. Thank you!